# how to check whether the entered table exists in database?

Tags: c#

I tried with this code..

```
string tabExist = "IF EXIST ( SELECT [name] FROM sys.table WHERE [name]=" + combCustomerName.Text + "" + ")";
        SqlCommand tabExistCmd = new SqlCommand(tabExist, con);
        tabExistCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It is showing exception Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.

Help me out to resolve it.

Comment: are you trying to return a bool here? or test existence then do something else in the one query?

Comment: if the table exists i want to print as table exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
string tabExist = "IF EXIST ( SELECT * FROM sys.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME =" + combCustomerName.Text +")";
    SqlCommand tabExistCmd = new SqlCommand(tabExist, con);
    tabExistCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
string tabExist = "IF EXIST ( SELECT count(*) FROM sys.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME =" + combCustomerName.Text +")";
        SqlCommand tabExistCmd = new SqlCommand(tabExist, con);
        if((int)tabExistCmd.ExecuteScalar()>0)
        {
          //Table Exist
        }
        else
        {
          //Table does not exist
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need just write *name*, and also *use parameters* in your query and not plaint text concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tablenamehere') IS NOT NULL [whatever else you want to do here]
```

Answer (score 0):

The predicate is called `EXISTS` and the table/view you test against if called `sys.tables` and finally the name needs to be quoted so try this:

```
string tabExist = "IF EXISTS ( SELECT [name] FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = '" + combCustomerName.Text + "')";
```

Your query is also incomplete, as it states that you want to do something if the condition holds true, but you never state what to do. A valid query would use this form:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT [name] FROM sys.tables WHERE [name]='Orders') SELECT 'TRUE' AS Status
```

This would return the string value `TRUE`if the table exists.

Also, you really shouldn't do concatenation for parameters, but rather use placeholders and parameters with the command object.